# Problems with values within a key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I'm having issues figuring out how to obtain a delta within the content of individual values, while using pandas:

Here's an example of my dataframe:  (I also don't know how to convert all the numbers that are held as strings to numbers).

`df =  pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID1','ID2', 'ID3'], 'SEQ': ['10 20', '20 25', '1 10 45 50' ]})`

```
0 ID1 10 20
1 ID2 20 25
2 ID3 1 10 45 50
```

And I want to obtain another column that has the values of the 2nd number minus the 1st value (ignoring the 1!) for every set of values from 'SEQ'. So, it would look like this:

`'Delta': [10,5,35]` (Those are the results of (20 - 10),(25 -20), and so on)

The final df would look like this:

```
  ID   SEQ          DELTA
0 ID1  10 20        10
1 ID2  40 45        5
2 ID3  1 10 45 50   35
```

Comment: Please proofread your question. It's not clear what is the problem and what is thing you want to achieve.

Comment: I added an example, maybe now it's  little bit clearer.

Comment: where does delta of 15 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `lambda`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'], 'SEQ': ['10 20', '20 25', '1 10 45 50']})
df['delta'] = df['SEQ'].map(lambda x: int(x.split()[1])-int(x.split()[0]) if x.split()[0] != '1' else int(x.split()[2])-int(x.split()[1]))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    ID         SEQ  delta
0  ID1       10 20     10
1  ID2       20 25      5
2  ID3  1 10 45 50     35
```

Comment: I tried to use it, but the error "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>" came up. Maybe i need to ad astype(int) somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @JuanMacD are you sure? I just copied your code as it's and it work!

Comment: Yep, but it might be that I'm actually working over a csv file, and I had some previous code that dealt with the  values over "SEQ". I'll work it out, the codes makes sense. (I didn't' put it in the question to make it easier to understand)Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(x):    
    
    val_list = x.split(" ")
    
    e = sum([int(val) for idx, val in enumerate(val_list) if idx%2 == 0 and int(val) != 1])
    o = sum([int(val) for idx, val in enumerate(val_list) if idx%2 == 1 and int(val) != 1])
    
    return abs(e - o)
        

df["DELTA"] = df["SEQ"].apply(func)
```